# BizTalk MQSC Adapter

Tags: biztalk, ibm-mq, host, biztalk-2009, zos

I am having problems testing the MQSC Adapter in BizTalk to communicate with a Queue on Z/OS Host.

The test senario: While sending messages though Biztalk I (Force)stop and start the Host channel, to mimic a HOST IPL.

In this scenario I experienced the following outcomes:

**Sometimes there are messages left uncomitted on the Host MQ.**
Even after the channel are started again. This way I don't know if the messages have been processed by Biztalk. 
**Question** Is there a way to make sure that messages are always committed on the Host MQ or still available on the MQ if not committed

**Once I experienced duplicate messages and once that messages was lost**
Since these things happened only once each. I hope to find problems in my test applications / procedure. 
**Not really a question**, but if others have experienced the same errors I would like to know.

**The test Setup**

- Biztalk 2009 on 2 nodes
- WebSphere MQ client 7.5.0.2 (Transactions supported)
- MSDTC - [XA Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg167382.aspx) are enabled (Edited to reflect comments)
- MS Biztalk Adapters for Host Systems 2.0
  [image: MS Biztalk Adapters for Host Systems 2.0]

**Port Configuration**
Receive Location
[image: Receive Location]

Send Port
[image: Send Port]

Comment: FWIW we used non-transactional 7.0.1 without issue on a 2 node BTS2009  group to an AIX MQ Host. Just to check, have you enabled [XA support on MSDTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg167382.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment StuartLC: Yes we have enabled XA Transactions on MSTDC.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MQ transactions, that is just MQPMO_SYNCPOINT and MQCMIT, then the disconnection (either explicitly or implicitly due to `STOP CHANNEL(chl-name) MODE(FORCE)`) will cause any outstanding transaction to be completed (committed on an explicit disconnection, rolled-back on an implicit one).

If you are using 2-PC transactions with a Transaction Manager (TM), then the transaction will need to be dealt with by the TM, depending on how far through it is, is it prepared already for example.